# How to colorize git push output

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

it's possible to create an git alias to colorize the output, in error case, of git push command?

I have one that works to log, but i can't modify it to works with push.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%C(62)\\ [%cn]\\ %ce" --decorate
```

example of error message:

> "error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://github.com/user/projectname.git'"

Comment: According to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/401533/is-there-anyway-to-color-git-push-output) it's not possible, but it's almost 2 years old. You can check the Git's source code.

Answer (score 4):

What should the push print?

push printout the result of the "pushed" code to the server. You can have server side hook which sends out colored messages to the user.

#### [`pre-receive hook`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#pre-receive-KpTEIPiaik)

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Output colors
red='\033[0;31m';
green='\033[0;32m';
yellow='\033[0;33m';
default='\033[0;m';

# personal touch :-)
echo "${red}"
echo "                                         "
echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
echo "                                         "
echo "                                         "
echo "      ${green}You have just committed code ${red}  " 
echo "      Your code ${yellow}is bad.!!!      "
echo "      ${red} Do not ever commit again    "
echo "                                         "
echo "${default}"
```

---

Comment: He probably wants to have error messages highlighted somehow.

Comment: I have posted a full working sample. Im using it as part of my repo hooks.

Comment: But the hook doesn't change the behavior of Git, it's just something executed in addition, it doesn't change what or how Git is printing to the console. Or does it receive the error message as an argument so you can print it again (so it will be printed twice)? Or I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Cool so you have the answer :-).

Comment: No one can miss such an error message ...... Trust me. Im updating the ascii are once in awhile to track attention

Comment: Please be kind to accept and vote since its the right answer for your question.